# Change of orientation stops the page numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I have page numbering set up.  When I change orientation on two pages (using "this point forward"), the first page using landscape mode no longer has the page number.  The second landscape page, and all the pages that go back to portrait also have it.  All pages before the orientation page also have it (except the first page, which is on purpose).  How to I fix this?  When I manually add the missing page number, it ends up adding it to the first page, which I don't want.

Comment: When you change the orientation of one or more pages so that you have a mix of landscape and portrait you introduce "sections" to the document. This creates logical breaks in the document and Word sees them as like new documents so page numbering can get messed up. For your second "new section" page you may want to create it as a new section. You can then apply page numbering without affecting the previous page number (as experienced). You can then use "start numbering from..." setting

Comment: If you have "Link to previous" set for the first page header/footer in the landscape section, what you do in that header/footer will be reflected in the first page header/footer of the previous section. So you need to unlink, and that may also mean that you need to create/recreate the header/footer in one or more sections.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

Change the orientation of the page - applying to selected text to make one page change orientation.

Format page numbers (Insert menu - Page number - Format page numbers), select 'Continue from previous section'.

You need to do this for the page you have changed and the one after that, and then it's fixed.

Comment: See my answer. You missed the different first page setting.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the option for "[Different First Page](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Different_First_Page)" in the second section (the landscape section).

If you want portrait page numbers on the landscape section, that takes a bit more. See [How to Put a Portrait Page Number on a Landscape Page](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/LandscapeSection.htm) by Bill Coan, MVP, Dave Rado, MVP, and Suzanne Barnhill, MVP.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the said page number > Format Page Numbering > Page numbering following the precedent (instead of "Starting from ...").

My headers are linked, this is probably mandatory. To link your headers, just do the exact opposite of [user181946's directives](https://superuser.com/questions/795734/change-of-orientation-stops-the-page-numbering#comment1038657_795734).

*PS: I translated the menu entries myself, sorry if it's not exactly how they are named in the english version of MS Word.*